# RFID Reads PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication

Tags: arduino, rfid, mfrc522

I am using an Arduino Uno and I am trying to read a RFID tag with a RC522 RFID Reader Module. The module is connected to the Uno like this: [RFID Module with Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvkLR.png)

I have downloaded and installed the Arduino IDE 1.8.19 and downloaded the library [Miguel RFID](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) to run the program.

Basically I have used this [tutorial](https://lastminuteengineers.com/how-rfid-works-rc522-arduino-tutorial/) to make this RFID project work.

I tried the `DumpInfo` and I encountered a problem with the tag that it cannot read sector 1 and 0 and gives me a `PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.` See example below.

```
Card UID: 06 2A BE 8C
Card SAK: 08
PICC type: MIFARE 1KB
Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits
15     63   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 BC FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       61   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       60   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
14     59   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       58   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       57   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       56   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
13     55   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       54   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       53   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       52   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
12     51   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ]   
       50   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       49   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       48   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
11     47   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       46   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       45   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       44   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
10     43   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       42   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       41   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       40   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 9     39   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       38   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       37   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       36   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 8     35   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       34   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       33   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       32   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 7     31   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       30   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       29   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       28   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 6     27   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       26   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       25   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       24   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 5     23   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       22   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       21   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       20   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 4     19   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       18   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       17   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       16   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 3     15   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       14   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       13   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
       12   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 2     11   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
       10   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
        9   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
        8   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
 1      7  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
 0      3  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
```

The tag is for opening doors of the appartment building but for some reason it cannot read sector 1 and 0. If I try with the tag that was included with the RFID module, their are no problems and the program can read all 16 sectors.

Can anyone help me with reading sector 1 and 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions might have been answered in the comments in this post here on [Arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37615/arduino-rfid-mifare-classic-dump-info).

If that didn't answer your question, you might wanna repost your question there for more expert answers.